# Jquery change id of child element

Tags: jquery

I am creating one new row like

```
 var newRow = $(this).closest('tr').clone().appendTo('#gridInAnswers').find('input').val('');
```

Now i want to change the id of the input element.How to do this? I am thinking of

```
var i = gridInAnsLength;
  $('input', newRow).each(function() {
    $(this)[0].id = "Col" + counter + "_" + (i++)
                 });
```

But its not workin.Please Suggest.

My html  mock up is like

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        div{ padding:4px; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(

        function() {
            var counter = 2;
            $('a.add').live('click', function() {
                if (counter > 5) {
                    alert("Only 5 textboxes allowed");
                    return false;
                }
                var newRow =
                $(this).closest('tr').clone().appendTo('#gridInAnswers').find('input').val('');

                var i = 2;
                $('input', newRow).each(function() {
                    $(this).attr("id", "Col"+ (i++));

                });

                $(this).text('Remove').removeClass('add').addClass('remove');
                counter++;
            });
            $('a.remove').live('click', function() {
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                counter--;
            });
            $("#getButtonValue").click(function() {
                var gridInAnswerValuesHtml = "";
                $(".grdAns").each(function() {
                    //ansString += this.value+",";
                    gridInAnswerValuesHtml += "<input type = \"hidden\" name = \"gridInAnswers\" value = \"";
                    gridInAnswerValuesHtml += this.value;
                    gridInAnswerValuesHtml += "\">";
                });
                alert(gridInAnswerValuesHtml);

            });


        });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table id="gridInAnswers">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Min Value
                </th>
                <th>
                    Max Value
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="col1" id="Col1_2" class="grdAns" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="col1" id="Col1_3" class="grdAns" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" class="add">Add</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <input type='button' value='Get TextBox Value' id='getButtonValue'>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
```

Comment: can you please format the code by using 10101 above the code or cntr-k

Answer (score 3):

use jquery's attr

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

```
$('#yourold').attr('id', 'newid');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method to set the id:

```
var i = gridInAnsLength;
$('input', newRow).each(function() {
    $(this).attr("id", "Col" + counter + "_" + (i++));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have change my solution and I think this will solve your problem. You need to change 2 things if this is ok with you.
First Change your id format to

```
id="Col_1_2"
id="Col_1_3"
```

Second, Replace your javascript code to this

```
    function() {
        var counter = 2;
        $('a.add').live('click', function() {
            if (counter > 5) {
                alert("Only 5 textboxes allowed");
                return false;
            }
            //var newRow=$(this).closest('tr').clone().appendTo('#gridInAnswers').find('input').val('');

            var newRowHTML = $(this).closest('tr').clone()[0].outerHTML;
            var theClone = $(this).closest('tr').clone().find('input');
            $(theClone).each(function(){
                var TheID = $(this).attr("id").split('_');
                newRowHTML=newRowHTML.replace($(this).attr("id"),TheID[0]+"_"+(parseInt(TheID[1])+1)+"_"+TheID[2]);

            });
            var newRow = $(newRowHTML).appendTo('#gridInAnswers').find('input').val('');
            var i = 2;

            $(this).text('Remove').removeClass('add').addClass('remove');
            counter++;
        });
        $('a.remove').live('click', function() {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            counter--;
        });
        $("#getButtonValue").click(function() {
            var gridInAnswerValuesHtml = "";
            $(".grdAns").each(function() {
                //ansString += this.value+",";
                gridInAnswerValuesHtml += "<input type = \"hidden\" name = \"gridInAnswers\" value = \"";
                gridInAnswerValuesHtml += this.value;
                gridInAnswerValuesHtml += "\">";
            });
            alert(gridInAnswerValuesHtml);
        });
    }
```

I'm sure this will solve your problem. Please don't forget to vote if it helps and also don't forget to mark as the answer if it solves your problem. Thanks! :)

Comment: Not workin...ids are not unique,in one tr its unique but getting repeated in next tr

Comment: @oddoneout , you mean the above code is doing like that or general you are saying, definetly ids should be unique

Comment: @oddoneout , print i value above or initialize to var i=0 or so , i think its not incrementing....

Comment: @gov ya but its not entering the function even

Comment: @OddOneOut hi do you have a sample html layout for this would you mind if I would take a look at it and see if I can find some work arounds. Thanks! :)

Comment: @  to be a programmer someday  ,added the html mockup

Comment: @OddOneOut hi I have editted my solution... Hope this works for you!